# How do I make Emacs honor ~/.fonts.conf?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, fonts, fontconfig

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 and I've installed the emacs-snapshot package via apt-get. When I run this Emacs, it honors my `~/.fonts.conf` file. (I can tell because the fonts change if I remove the file.)

I've also installed Emacs by compiling the source. Most recently, I installed Emacs 24.1.1 (however this problem occurred for version 23 as well). When I run the Emacs compiled from source, it does not seem to honor my `~/.fonts.conf` file. (The fonts look the same whether the file exists or not.)

How can I make Emacs compiled from source honor my `~/.fonts.conf` file?

This is the contents of my `~/.fonts.conf` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
   <const>rgb</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
   <const>hintfull</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you configured emacs, did it say something about fontconfig not being found?  You can check in `config.log` after the fact.

If it said it couldn't find fontconfig, try installing the package `libfontconfig1-dev` and running `configure` again.